# Remove unwanted commas from string using php

Tags: php

My result was like this

```
$str = 189 Exeter Road, , , , , Harrow, Middlesex
```

I want above string as

```
$str = 189 Exeter Road, Harrow, Middlesex
```

How to remove all those commas in php. Is there any way to clear

I used

```
$var = preg_replace('/,{2,}/', ',', trim($str, ','));
```

Comment: How is the string generated in the 1st place?

Comment: I got result. thank you all

Comment: Glad you have a solution, but it would probably be better not to generate the exta commas in the 1st place. If you show how you generate the string you would probably get a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) into an array, then clear out the empty elements with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and finally [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) back to a string

```
$str = '189 Exeter Road, , , , , Harrow, Middlesex';

$str = implode(', ', array_filter(explode(', ', $str)));
```

Comment: Thank you all, I got result from all.

Answer (score 2):

This capture comma with trailing space, and if more than 2 times, replace with 1 comma with space

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/iV0gI3/1)

```
$str = "189 Exeter Road, , , , , Harrow, Middlesex";

echo preg_replace("/(,\s){2,}/", ", ", $str); // 189 Exeter Road, Harrow, Middlesex
```

Answer (score 1):

try below solution:

```
$str = '189 Exeter Road, , , , , Harrow, Middlesex';

$data = explode(',', $str);
$data = array_map('trim', $data);
$data = array_filter($data);
echo implode(',', $data);
```